# How to set spark.akka.frameSize in spark-shell?

Tags: apache-spark

For a particular **spark shell** session, I am attempting

```
spark-shell -Dspark.akka.frameSize=10000 --executor-memory 4g
```

Within the shell, I get this:

```
System.getProperty("spark.executor.memory")
res0: String = 4g
System.getProperty("spark.akka.frameSize")
res1: String = null
```

It could be this string is incorrect, but I get a frameSize error when attempting to do a take() on my dataset.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 6:0 was 12518780 bytes which exceeds spark.akka.frameSize (10485760 bytes). Consider using broadcast variables for large values.
```

This shows a frameSize of the default 10M. Perhaps I have the wrong syntax. Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in Spark's configuration guide under [Dynamically Loading Spark Properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties):

> The Spark shell and `spark-submit` tool support two ways to load configurations dynamically. The first are command line options, such as `--master`, as shown above. `spark-submit` can accept any Spark property using the `--conf` flag, but uses special flags for properties that play a part in launching the Spark application.

For example:

```
./bin/spark-submit --name "My app" --master local[4] --conf spark.akka.frameSize=100 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" myApp.jar
```

Comment: you should use ./bin/spark-submit --properties-file spark-job.conf and put all the configuration in the spark-job.conf file.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax works within the spark shell:

```
spark-shell  --executor-memory 4g --driver-java-options "-Dspark.akka.frameSize=100"
```

This was terrifically non-obvious in the Spark documentation.  Clearly, that still needs a lot of work.

This was in 1.0.1.  It appears Josh's answer below works for 1.1.0+